How to request shifts when nurses _don't_ work
So I am working on a variation of the nurse scheduler.
This includes then the ability to have nurses request when they are going to be on...
However, I need to be able to support requests for when nurses want to be off.
It's not quite the same as simply negating the requests to be on as that won't mean they're not working during the "opposite" time.
It just means they will be allocated when they requested.
So far I've got something like:
LinearExprBuilder obj = LinearExpr.newBuilder();
for (int n : allNurses) {
  for (int d : allDays) {
    for (int s : allShifts) {
      if (shiftRequests[n][d][s] == 1) {
        obj.addTerm(shifts[n][d][s].not(), 1);
      } else {
        obj.addTerm(shifts[n][d][s], 0);
      }
    }
  }
}
model.maximize(obj);

So I negate the bool when multiplying it (sorry for the java code, it's not very elegant).
Remember my request array now contains 1's where the nurses has requested to be off and 0's where they are fine with being on
But this doesn't work. Perhaps I need to include this "not" var in my model so that it can be actively tracked? And just adding it here is not enough?

You can have a look at the shift_scheduling_sat example.
The first idea is to create an 'off' shift.
From there, the example supports both types of requests:

nurse prefer this assignment (including the off type)
nurse does not like this assignment.

The implementation relies on adding a positive or negative penalty on the corresponding Boolean variable or its (logical) negation.

If choices/preferences is a given like nurse-day-shift you can define a pre-set parameter $p_{n,ds}$ where $ds$ can be a single index for day-shift combo (just to make it compact). Also $p_{n,ds}=1$ if shift $ds$ is preferred, $0$ otherwise.
Then add an objective term to $max \sum_{n,ds} x_{n,ds}p_{n,ds}$ where $x$ is binary variable of assignment.
